# How to customize login?

Tags: angular, ngx-admin

I am using [angular4](/questions/tagged/angular4). I want to customize the login page in the [ngx-admin](/questions/tagged/ngx-admin). Is there any solution? Or it is good to create a new login page in [ngx-admin](/questions/tagged/ngx-admin) instead of customizing the existing one.

Comment: Login page is hard to customizing. Create new one instead.

Comment: thanks@Maximi , Am trying to create a new one

Comment: Is there any idea to hide the nb-menu in ngx admin for the new login page ?

Comment: Actually I found the template in NPM. Only the way to customise it is change CSS. Little confused for me also, but this is life...

Comment: ok.Thanks a lot @Maximi

Answer (score 16):

According to [this link](https://github.com/akveo/nebular/blob/8ef741268f0eab8821e0dd301e98ae58082afd1d/src/framework/auth/UPGRADE.md) and [this issue](https://github.com/akveo/nebular/issues/37#issuecomment-350829049)
The following changes can be made to customize/ extend the existing the auth-pages/components in ngx-admin (without the npm dependency)

First Copy all source files from [this repository folder](https://github.com/akveo/nebular/tree/master/src/framework/auth) to 
       `'theme/components/auth'` of your project

1. in file `core.module.ts` change following imports:

```
import { NbAuthModule, NbDummyAuthStrategy } from '@nebular/auth';
```

to

```
import { NbAuthModule, NbDummyAuthStrategy } from '../@theme/components/auth'; // '@nebular/auth';
```

2. in file `app-routing.module.ts` change following imports

```
import {
  NbAuthComponent,
  NbLoginComponent,
  NbLogoutComponent,
  NbRegisterComponent,
  NbRequestPasswordComponent,
  NbResetPasswordComponent,
} from '@nebular/auth';
```

to

```
import {
  NbAuthComponent,
  NbLoginComponent,
  NbLogoutComponent,
  NbRegisterComponent,
  NbRequestPasswordComponent,
  NbResetPasswordComponent,
} from './@theme/components/auth'; //'@nebular/auth'
```

4.in file `theme.module.ts` add following imports

```
// this line in import part of the file
import {NbAuthModule} from './components/auth';
import {NbPasswordAuthStrategy} from "./components/auth/strategies";

// inside of const NB_THEME_PROVIDERS
NbAuthModule.forRoot({
  providers: {
    email: {
      service: NbPasswordAuthStrategy,
      config: {},
    }
  }
}).providers,
```

References

- https://github.com/akveo/nebular/issues/37
- https://github.com/akveo/nebular/blob/8ef741268f0eab8821e0dd301e98ae58082afd1d/src/framework/auth/UPGRADE.md

Comment: What is the path of core.module.ts file?

Answer (score 3):

In order to use customize login page you just have to do following steps.

**Note:**

I have created login component inside pages folder.

[image]

**Version**

> Your global Angular CLI version (8.3.9) is greater than your local
>   version (8.0.2). The local Angular CLI version is used.

**Step#1**

Replace route component with your component name like this inside **app-routing.module.ts**

```
 path: 'auth',
component: NbAuthComponent,
children: [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LoginComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
  },
```

**Step#2**

Import component in **theme.modules.ts**

> located inside /src/app/@theme

```
 import {LoginComponent} from '../../app/pages/login/login.component'
 const COMPONENTS = [
 HeaderComponent,
 FooterComponent,
 SearchInputComponent,
 TinyMCEComponent,
 OneColumnLayoutComponent,
 ThreeColumnsLayoutComponent,
 TwoColumnsLayoutComponent,
 LoginComponent   // HERE
];
```

**Step#3**

Put component inside declaration of **pages.module.ts**

```
declarations: [
PagesComponent,
LoginComponent,
],
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: do you have sample repo where this works?

Comment: Dhaval shah , I actually implemented on this https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin , repo of current project is not available

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to use Ngx-admin existing login page because it is very easy to customize. You can simply set it by setting the **endpoint** and you can also modify the existing by copying the source code from ngx-admin documentation.

Comment: can you explain how can we alter existing component?